# Showing count data can be dichotomized without losing too much information

Tags: count-data, binning

I am working with a set of data that has accident counts by year from taxi drivers.

```
no.accident <- c(16003, 2355, 4433, 18823)
one.accident <- c(172, 26, 232, 9)
two.accident <- c(0, 0, 3, 0)
df <- data.frame(no.accident=no.accident, 
       one.accident=one.accident, two.accident=two.accident)
```

year 1 there were 16003 accident-free drivers, 172 divers had 1 accident, no driver had 2 accidents, year 3 4433 drivers were accident-free, 232 drivers had 1 accident and 3 drivers had 2 accidents.

I wish to show that the data can be analyzed either as a count data or a "0 vs at least 1 accident" binomial data. Could anyone kindly suggest a way to statistically show it--any hypothesis test or regressions?

Comment: Needless dichotomization of ordinal or continuous variables always loses information.

Comment: I wish to dichotomize because I need to estimate rate of accident without any information on time of accident. All I know about these counts is that they are tallied at the end of a 14-day sampling interval... Any suggestions given that I have no time information?

Comment: From that I gather that you could estimate both the probability of any accident and the mean number of accidents, among other quantities.  The Poisson distribution may come into play.